# Окказионализм "ребетята" (малышня) через "е" или "я": ребятята?

Tags: окказионализмы

> И я вспомнила, каково это – играть, и я рассмотрела в тёплом свете
>   лампы своё достойное кольцо (подаренное Джоном на помолвку), и чуть не
>   крикнула: «Эй, а спокойной ночи?!»  – вослед волне светловолосых
>   **ребятят**, несущихся по лестнице особняка вверх, в свои спальни, и растроганно шмыгнула носом в трубку…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окказионализм ***ребетята*** довольно часто используется в разговорной речи, причем иногда так называют и взрослых (по аналогии  с ребятами).

Черепашки ещё совсем ***ребетята***.

Будь счастлива, радостна, ***ребетята*** пусть радуют...

Стрельников Владимир Валериевич › Переярок:
Ну, тогда вам, ***ребетята***, точно стоит купить "Махиндру", если деньги есть...

**Пояснение**

Слово ***ребятёнок*** известно еще со времен Даля, причем оно имело также форму мн. числа ***ребятёнки***. Эти слова использовались до самого последнего времени, но в современном языке они выглядят стилистически устаревшими:

«А **ребятенки-то** хоть есть ли у них?» [Владимир Крупин. Балалайка // Библиотека «Огонек», 1989]

Возле бабы толпились замурзанные, посиневшие от холода **посадские ребятенки**, просили подудеть в утушки-свистульки. [Евгений Богданов. Вьюга (1972)]

Современные "ребятенки" совсем не такие, и называть их тоже надо другим словом. А каким?

Формально получается так: реб/ёнок — реб/ят/а — ребят/ёнок — ребят/ят/а. Странная такая цепочка, да и выглядит форма **ребятята** не лучшим образом.

А если так: **ребята — реб/ЕТ/ята,** в виде приговорки с повтором и лишним слогом.

Итак, ***ребята-ребетята.*** Вот и новое сложное слово получилось.

Comment: А вот здесь через **я**: – Ну, тогда вам, ребятята, точно стоит купить «Махиндру»... (дважды) https://books.google.ee/books?id=8y9yDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT114&lpg=PT114&dq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=CISMydyICq&sig=ACfU3U1Kcu1OGVZKCMIRjAdzp73BVPbpZA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDhaGJjOPhAhVvmIsKHRRRCeYQ6AEwC3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0&f=false Ребята - ребятня - ребятёнок - ребятята

Comment: Графика у слова ребятята  не из лучших  (останавливает на себе ненужное внимание), поэтому и частотность выше у   "ребетята."  Написание подобных слова не обязательно соответствует стандартной словообразовательной схеме, на то они и окказионализмы.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж пользоваться "прецедентным принципом", то я бы предпочёл смотреть у более именитых писателей. Например, у Эдуарда Успенского **ребятята**:

> А вокруг кишели веселые ребятята.